# "Have something to eat" in American English

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

I wonder what "have something to eat" means in American English and whether the examples below are correct/sound natural.

Is it similar to "have a snack," "have a meal," "have breakfast," etc? By that, I mean: Is it a fixed expression and means something similar to "eat something"?
Or maybe it means "to possess" and has a literal meaning, such as I have some food.

Are these examples sound natural to you:
1 - Would you like to have something to eat?
2 - Don't worry. I have something to eat at home.

I am confused because I have only found this expression in two dictionaries:

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/eat
"have something/nothing to eat (=eat something/nothing) We'll leave after we've had something to eat."

https://www.yourdictionary.com/have-something-to-eat
"(idiomatic) To eat something."

Some aspect of this question was answered here, but I do feel this answer doesn't exhaust my question:
here: [Do you have / Have you had something to eat'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/do-you-have-have-you-had-something-to-eat)

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with American English specifically?  These would be understood in any variety of English.  To have something to eat can mean two things, either "to posses something to eat" or "to eat something".  The meaning depends on the context. The verb **have** has several meanings which are context dependent.

Comment: @Billy Kerr I'm learning American English with the book "Basic Vocabulary in Use" (60 units of vocabulary practice in North American English), and sometimes they give a British alternative, e.g., pants mean different things in British and American English.
I was wondering how Americans used the phrase "have something to eat" because there's a chance they used it differently. A good example is ordering food. Correct me if I'm wrong, but an American would say: "Can I get...?" whereas a British person would say, "Can I have...?" /Could I please have..."

Comment: @Billy Kerr I do believe the phrase "have something to eat" is universally understood in all kinds of English, but I was particularly interested in an American version.

Comment: This is neither British nor American usage.  It's used all over. You shouldn't assume differences when there are none.  Note also that when an American says "Can I get" a British person can understand this, it's still English and 100% fully understandable, just that we tend to have different social etiquette rules here, where "can I get" is viewed as less polite. It's fine to say this in your own house or to your family, but not in a restaurant.  Americans are also fully capable of understanding something like "Could I please have".

Comment: Not everything in a  book like that only applies to AmE. Notice: It's not about **basic vocabulary**. It is about a phrase. Some Americans say (in terms of a menu), Can I get x? but some never say that. They might say: I'll have the [x]. Personally, I never use "Can I get x"; I use: May I have the x, please.

Comment: I have a snack. Would you like to exchange?

Comment: "and sometimes they give a British alternative, e.g., pants mean different things in British and American English. I was wondering how Americans used the phrase "have something to eat" because there's a chance they used it differently." - well, *did your book list a British alternative this time*, or otherwise talk about a usage difference? If not, then you should assume that the idiom is **not** specific to AmE.

Comment: @BillyKerr from the anecdotes I've heard, American food-service staff are lucky if they hear "can I get" nowadays. It comes across that customers, especially at fast-food places or cheaper "family" restaurants, will more likely start out with something like "yeah, I need". (For me as a Canadian, I find I commonly start with "Hi, yes, I'll have".)

Comment: My goodness people, what's with the completely uncalled-for vitriol over OQ mentioning "American English" in their question? They're a *learner* on a site for *learners*. How many questions or comments on this site go into the difference between AmE and BrE in certain contexts ... just answer the question and explain there's no difference, there's no need to drag them for the audacity of asking about a phrase in a certain dialect.

Answer (score 18):

There are two senses of "Have something to eat".  One is literal, it means "possess food", the second is idiomatic, and it means to consume food (usually a snack). This also applies to the other expressions, like ‘have a snack’

The interpretation is contextual, so

> Would you like to have something to eat?

This is an offer to supply food for immediate consumption. It means "would you like to consume food". The alternative (Would you like to possess food?) wouldn't be a normal question to ask.

> I have something to eat at home.

This is a statement about the possession of food.  The alternative (I habitually eat a light snack at home) wouldn't make much sense.

Of course just by changing the context slightly you can change the interpretation:

> I have something to eat when I get home each day.  (consume food)

Comment: Oddly enough, “Would you like to have something to eat?” would _not_ usually be an offer to supply food to me. If I were offering food, I would always simply ask, “Would you like something to eat?”, but when you add in _to have_, it becomes a question of preference rather than an offer to procure. It does actually become more of a question of possession, roughly ‘would you like to have some food made available [in whatever not-immediate situation we’re talking about]?’. I think this is more down to the properties of _like_ than _have something to eat_, though.

Comment: In American English we can say "I'd like to have (a little) something to eat" and the meaning would be "to eat now, I'm feeling peckish". The phrase "something to eat" is synonymous with "food" and "have" can be a synonym for "consume". An offer of food to be eaten later, perhaps as a snack on a journey, would probably use the verb "take": *Would you like to take someting to eat?*   In the US, we don't use "take" to mean "eat", though we do "take" medicines by mouth.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Your point is well-made, but one might informally tell a friend (using the imperative) "have something to eat", meaning "share in what I am eating."

Comment: It would be useful to stress that this is the same in AmE/BrE.

Comment: @Wastrel Yes, absolutely. That’s part of the reason why I think the specific phenomenon whereby the ‘eat’ interpretation is made less likely than the ‘possess’ interpretation depends more on the properties of the verb _like_, specifically questions with _like_. As a parallel to @Tim’s example of snacks for a trip, consider the planning of a party/reception/meeting, where “Would you like to have something to eat?” would mean whether there should be snacks available for the guests. That’s the primary context I could see myself using the construction.

Comment: (Extra comment to tag @TimR, since I could only tag one person in the previous comment.)

Comment: You are sitting in a bar (that serves food) drinking beer, and one person says to another: Would you like to have something to eat? That bar can be in the UK or US. have something to eat/have something to drink are basically idioms. –

Comment: So you *can* have your cake and eat it too!

Comment: If we take the second meaning (*to eat something*) into account why do we use *have* to mean eating here, while the verb *eat* is there itself?

Comment: Re: "The alternative (Would you like to possess food?) wouldn't be a normal question to ask."  I am now imagining a tone deaf reporter interviewing victims of a famine or crop failure and asking "Would you like to have something to eat?"

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this also applies to the other expressions, like ‘have a snack’: ‘Would you like to have a snack?’ (or, following the comment by @JanusBahsJacquet above, ‘Would you like a snack?’) has meaning (1), while ‘I have a snack at home.’ has the more literal meaning (2).  (But ‘I'll have a snack at home.’ is back to meaning (1) again.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context. If you ask "Would you like to have something to eat?" around mealtime, it's an offer to prepare or provide that meal. If you ask at some other time, it's offering a snack.

In contexts where "have" is not used in an active sense, it has its literal meaning of possession.

Answer (score 0):

Those examples might not be grammatically incorrect, but they very clearly do not sound natural; not at all.

The first should be 'Would you like something to eat?' without 'to have'. There might be grammatical explanations and either way, the example is unidiomatic and could never sound natural.

The second is in no way ungrammatical but again, it's wholly unidiomatic and could never sound natural.

Whatever else, there is no likelihood that any native speaker of British - and in my limited experience, US American or Australian - English would ever use 'Don't worry…' in that context.

'I have something to eat at home' is fine grammatically, but the correct idiom would always be 'I will eat at home.'

Very differently 'I have something to eat at home' might sound natural to some African users of English - in my limited experience South African, Zambian or Zimbabwean which is to say, people whose first language is Bantu, including Shona, Sindebele and Zulu but any similarity in meaning is cultural, not usefully linguistic.

My suggestion is that in 'ordinary' English 'Would you like to have something to eat?' would only ever be used for something as obscure and unlikely as 'Would you like to go home and find that there was something in your kitchen to eat?'

Largely in contrast 'Would you like something to eat?' means broadly 'Are you hungry? Would you like to eat something here and now?'

Answer (score -1):

The examples are correct and natural-sounding, and they simply reflect two of the multiple meanings of the word "have". To see a dictionary definition of "have" meaning to eat, see definition 12 in the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have) dictionary (American), or definition 15 in the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have_1) (British).

With food, it is totally natural to use either the "possess" or the "eat" meanings, as your two examples show. As with so many things, the meaning is understood from context. As you can see from the dictionary entries, there are many more meanings as well.

Comment: Cf. the notorious expression "have your cake and eat it too"